# Executing base class overridden method in derived class

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 application where the application has a QToolBox which consist of 2 pages of different user interface.

So for the MainWindow itself, I've created a base class called `BPAPOIApp` class to do whatever actions that maybe directly to the MainWindow.

And I've created another derived class that inherits the `BPAPOIApp` class for each of the QToolBox page because each of them have separated actions to be done.

Inside the base class I have a method called `def init_signals` to initiate all the action signals that is related to the base class, meanwhile I wanted to have another `def init_signals` in both of the derived classes (for 2 pages in QToolBox) which means the method will be overridden. Is there a proper way to initiate the `init_signals` method of all classes (base and derived) because both of them is waiting for different events to be occurred.

below are some of the codes that is related.

```
class BPAPOIApp(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super(BPAPOIApp, self).__init__()
    self._widget = QWidget()
    self._ui = Ui_Form()
    self._widget.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self._ui.setupUi(self._widget)
    self._ui.label.hide()

    self.init_signals()
    
def init_signals(self):
    self._ui.close_tbtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self._widget.hide())
    self._ui.information.clicked.connect(self.information_display)
    self._ui.toolBox.currentChanged.connect(self.reset_info)

def information_display(self):
    self._ui.label.setText('Test text')
    self._ui.label.show()
```

and below is the `BPAApp` class.

```
class BPAApp(BPAPOIApp):

def __init__(self):
    super(BPAApp, self).__init__()

    self.init_signals()

def init_signals(self):
    super().init_signals()        # try to instantiate base class signals here
    self._ui.radio_btn1.toggled.connect(self.option_selected)
    self._ui.radio_btn2.toggled.connect(self.option_selected)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bpa = BPAApp()
```

When I triggered `information` button `(self._ui.information)` the label did not show up in the interface, what might be wrong here?

Comment: No need to call the `self.init_signals()` within the derived class `BPAApp.__init__()` because it is already being called within the parent class `BPAPOIApp.__init__()`. When the parent class calls it, MRO would point it to the most derived implementation which is the derived `BPAApp.init_signals()` (which in turn calls the parent `BPAPOIApp.init_signals()`).

Comment: I see, that's what I missed! Thanks for pointing out. You may want to answer the question so I can accept it.

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano something doesn't add up: the fact that `init_signals` is called *again* shouldn't prevent the connection to work: in fact, it would call `information_display` *twice*. While the observation is correct, it doesn't seem to relate to the question, unless the OP left out important parts of the code (or didn't provide a correct [mre]).

Comment: @ReverseEngineer please always try to provide [mre]s, because your code seems to be missing important parts of its logic (see the comment above). Also, why are you creating a QWidget *inside* `BPAPOIApp`, which already is a QWidget? It seems like you're not using the `BPAPOIApp` instance at all, if not as a "controller" class, but if that's the case, inheriting from QWidget is completely pointless.

Comment: @musicamante, regarding to your 2 questions, 1. Yes, I notice that when I had `init_signals` in the derived class `__init__` function. But after removing it the `information_display` only called once.  Even though I did not post my full code but I believe the code posted above should be the minimum reproducible example already. 2. Inheriting `QWidget` is a mistake I found out after that, so I had remove it, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @ReverseEngineer Then sorry but your last question in the post is a bit confusing: you said that the label didn't show up, but according to your code it should (since the function has been connected, and it's also called twice due to the duplicate call). Then again, I cannot fully test your code exactly because you didn't provide a MRE; it is *not* reproducible since: 1. it's missing code that completely prevent its running, so we can only "reproduce" it in our minds (which can be perfectly fine), but 2. based on what you provided, it does *not* reproduce your issue.

Comment: Also, I don't know what `BPAPOIApp` inherits from, but consider that PyQt works better by creating subclasses for the widgets (forms, dialogs, etc) and implementing their functions instead of having a "global controller". Furthermore, if that is a QApplication subclass, then it's fine, but if it's a basic python object be aware that that pattern could create issues at some point, because many PyQt features are based on QObject subclasses: custom signals cannot be added to classes that don't inherit from QObject, and that could also represent an issue for multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to call the `self.init_signals()` within the derived class `BPAApp.__init__()` because it is already being called within the parent class `BPAPOIApp.__init__()`. When the parent class calls it, [MRO](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-resolution-order-in-python-inheritance/) would point it to the most derived implementation which is the derived `BPAApp.init_signals()` (which in turn calls the parent `BPAPOIApp.init_signals()`).